# Is there any spying utility is available for Universal Windows Application?

Tags: xaml, uwp, snoop

I have used Snoop application as spying utility for my WPF application to find the focus of ui element. Like the same, there is any spying utility is available for Universal Windows (UWP) applications. I have also tried with XamlSpy utility for my application but it doesn't working efficiently. Is there any other utility is available for UWP applications?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For UWP apps you have 2 options:

- Use [XAML Spy](http://xamlspy.com/), which is a paid tool.
- Use [Live Visual Tree / Live Property Explorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt270227.aspx) in Visual Studio 2015 (or higher)

Comment: @Bart The XAML Spy does not support VisualStudio 2017 and it can not find the routed event.